# Second Prototype Cells not visible

Tags: ios

In my project I have created two prototype cells with the same class name but with different identifiers but I can't view the second prototype cell. I don't know what mistake I have done.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (indexPath.row==0)
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"Cell";
        InsureCell *cell = (InsureCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];

        cell.PolicyName.text=@"Hey I am Cell";

        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";
        InsureCell *cell = (InsureCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
         cell.PolicyName.text=@"Hey I am Cell2";
         return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug? Is it running the code to return the 'second' cell?

Comment: Where do your cells come from? A Storyboard? A XIB? Show us more details. Why do you need different cell reuse identifiers is using the same subclass?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the return > 0 on this both methods:

```
func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int)->Int
{
   return 1
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView:UITableView!)->Int
{
    return 1
}
```

Check either if when you run the app it show some error on console and update your question.

Comment: Given that he's checking to see if `indexPath.Rows` is zero or not, he has to return something greater than `1` from the `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon what you mean by "can't view". If the cell is appearing, but the text label isn't getting updated, that would happen if the second cell's outlet was not hooked up properly. Double check that the outlets in that second cell have been hooked up. You can check this by selecting the second cell in Interface Builder and examine the outlets in the "Connections Inspector" (the last tab on the panel on the right side of Interface Builder).

However if the cell is not appearing at all, it might happen if `numberOfRowsInSection` was not returning a value greater than 1.